# Angularfire2 list query limitToLast

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I want to access a specific node in my firebase database.

[image]

I actually run with :

- "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
- "firebase": "^4.9.0",

The code in my component looks like this :

```
  this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'); 
  auth.appUser$.subscribe(appUser => this.appUser = appUser );  

  if (this.id) 
  {
      //Live game state info          
      this.subscription = this.gameService.getLive(this.id).subscribe(action => {
        this.game = action.payload.val(); 
        console.log(this.game);
      });
    }
}
```

My function called in my gameService looks like this :

```
 getLive(gameId) 
  {
    return this.db.object('/games/live/' + gameId).snapshotChanges();
  }
```

The problem is that I don't know how to access the node "StartedAt" in the rounds.. However I can see all the complete node from my actual "game":

[image]

How can I access the "startedAt" from a specific round ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Component :

```
      this.subscription = this.gameService
      .getLive(this.id)
      .subscribe(action => {
        this.game = {key: action.key, value: action.payload.val()};
        this.game.value.playerList = Object.values(this.game.value.playerList);
```

> this.game.value.rounds = Object.values(this.game.value.rounds);

```
        console.log(this.game.value.rounds[this.game.value.rounds.length-1]);
      });
    }
```

Game model :

```
import { Round } from './round';
import { Player } from './player';

export interface Game {
 key: string,
 value:{
 state: string, 
 playerList: Player[], 
 rounds: Round[], 
 startedAt: string,
 roundCounter: string,
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`game.rounds[roundId].startedAt`